# Python:Change I make on class file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Whenever I edit a class file, the new stuff does not appear when I run it.It runs the old version.
The new stuff only shows up when I close Python,and open it from the beginning.

How to fix this problem?

I use Python 2.7 Canopy on Windows XP.

Comment: What's a Python window? Are you using an IDE or something?

Comment: Man, all these change and close and save and import and execute and open. Why not just post code instead?

Comment: ok. sorry. I use python on windows and Canopy.

Comment: Whenever I edit a class file, the new stuff does not appear when I run it.It runs the old version.
The new stuff only shows up when I close Python,and open it from the beginning.

How to fix this problem? 

I use Python 2.7 Canopy on Windows XP.

Comment: Did you re-import your class after your modification?

Comment: what is re-import? I do not think so. I just click on run for the file I import the class after modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python imports each file only once.

So if you edit `test.py` and then do `import test` a second time, nothing changes. You need to explicitly [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload) the module:

```
>>> import test
>>> # edit test.py
>>> reload(test)    # NOT import test!
```